# Expected number of trials

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Consider independent trials, each of which is a success with probability *p* and derive the expected number of trials needed to obtain *k* consecutive successes by

(a)conditioning on the time of the first failure

(b)conditioning on the time that it takes to obtain *k-1* consecutive successes

ANS.

I am thinking the answer to this question. but still I am unable.

Comment: If this is a homework or assignment question, please add the [self-study] tag. Also could you show us how you have approached the question and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like the self-study tag is appropriate here. Anyhow take a look at the [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: Please edit your post to include the `self-study` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).  There are lots of people here waiting to help, but they would like to see your thought process and how far you got in your reasoning.  Thanks!

Comment: @Andy You can see how I have approached the question and what I have tried so far. Please edit it, if I have made any mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us solve part (b) of question first. Here *X* is geometric with parameter *p* if

P{X=k}=$p^{k-1}q,$, k=1,2,...  where *q=1-p*
Hence, its moment generating function is
$\phi(t)=E[e^{tx}]$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{tk}p^{k-1}q$

$=qe^t\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(pe^t)^{k-1}$

$=\frac{qe^t}{1-pe^t}$

Differentiation gives

$\phi'(t)=\frac{(1-pe^t)qe^t+qe^tpe^t}{(1-pe^t)^2}$
$=\frac{qe^t}{1-pe^t}$
Evaluation at t=0 gives

E[X]=$\frac{q}{(1-p)^2}=\frac1q$

If we solve part(a) in this way, we get the answer $\frac{p}{q^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-Here trials follows Negative Binomial Distribution.(type-2 & type-1 respectively)

So then,
(a) $\frac{P(success)}{P(failure)}$

(b) $\frac{1}{P(failure)}$